# ORACLE SQL: Find all column values for a given value sorted by year

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm looking to find the `GRANT_ID` values in  the APPLIES_TSSA/CD/CTT tables for user '3392398' and have the return sorted by `YEAR`.

This is my current code:

```
SELECT GRANT_ID
  FROM APPLIES_TSSA, APPLIES_CD, APPLIES_CTT
 WHERE ( APPLIES_TSSA.COYOTE_ID
       , APPLIES_CD.COYOTE_ID
       , APPLIES_CTT.COYOTE_ID = ('3392398')
 GROUP BY to_date('DD-MM-YYYY') <= to_date('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

My schema is as follows [(link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbyb9.jpg):

[image: schema]

Comment: Can you post the definitions of these tables and how they are related? You SQL doesn't make it clear.

Comment: I don't think 'Da Fake One' is asking a serious question

Comment: Sorry stupid email account I have for all my login accounts.

Comment: @Ben here is a Relational Diagram that would help I hope http://i.imgur.com/Siqf4.jpg

Comment: I must be getting old; the diagram is unreadable.  You also seem to be referring to names like APPLIES_TSSA that are abbreviated to TSSA in the diagram.  It would be a whole heap easier if you showed the CREATE TABLE statements with primary and foreign key information (and no storage control information) for the three tables you seem to be concerted with.

Answer (score 2):

If you want things sorted by year, then use `order by`, not `group by`.  Also, learn to use proper join syntax.  I think the query is something like:

```
SELECT GRANT_ID, tss.year
FROM APPLIES_TSSA tssa join
       APPLIES_CD cd
       on tssa.COYOTE_ID = cd.COYOTE_ID join
       APPLIES_CTT ctt
       on tssa.Coyote_ID = ctt.COYOTE_ID
 where CTT.COYOTE_ID = ('3392398')
 order by tssa.year desc
```

Comment: My professor didn't go over join tables, this was just a query question that was given.  Much appreciated btw, I ran the query and it returns a this message with it emphasizing on 'where'

ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Get rid of the parentheses in the WHERE clause and try again.  Either that or substitute 'IN' for '='.

Comment: @BobJarvis . . . The problem was that I left out the second `on` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am getting this error.  ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00904:"TSSA"."YEAR": invalid identifier when running the fixed query.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @voyeurlei . . . I saw the "year" column in the data structure.  Perhaps you need something like `to_char(<some date field>, 'YYYY')`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried that field good sir, now i'm getting this error SELECT GRANT_ID
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: @voyeurlei . . . You need to prefix the column name with the table that you want to get it from . . . something like `tssa.Grant_id` or `ctt.Grant_id`.  I just based this on your original query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks that worked great!  Is there a way to display the given year?